# How to send base64 Image source to Controller after cropping (using croppie)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I'm trying to send a base64 image view to controller after cropping using (Croppie tool). But string is coming empty in controller even after same name. If i send using ajax then i could not get model data (tbl_product)

I already try to send back data using ajax & i successfully get image source in parameter but i could not getting my Model Data (tbl_product) its going empty

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(Tbl_Product product,HttpPostedFileBase file_photo, string base64image)
        {
            string name = null;
            string ext = null;


            if (ModelState.IsValid==true)
            {
                if (file_photo != null)
                {
                    name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file_photo.FileName);
                    ext = Path.GetExtension(file_photo.FileName);

                    string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ProductImages"), name + ext);
                    file_photo.SaveAs(path);
                }

                product.ProductImage = name + ext;
                product.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                _unitofwork.GetRepositoryInstance<Tbl_Product>().Add(product);
                return RedirectToAction("Product");

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.CategoryList = GetCategory();
                return View();
            }
        }
```

i'm Expected to get original image, croping image & save into folder & database and product data.

Comment: Seeing your request (ideally the raw request) would be helpful.

Comment: Use `System.Convert.ToBase64String`

Answer (score 0):

In the question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012606) I answered this answer.

I am posting a solution to upload cropping by **Croppie.js** to the server,

maybe it will help someone in the future.

**js**

```
// When you click for saving your crop
$("#upload-crop").on("click", function() {
  $uploadCrop.croppie('result', {
    type: 'base64',
    size: 'viewport',
    format: 'jpg',
  }).then(function (resp) {
    // Remove data:image/png;base64,
    var base64str = resp.substring(resp.indexOf(',') + 1);

    // If you want to show the crop result
    $('#img-result').attr('src', resp);
    // If you used a modal bootstrap
    $('#modal-crop').modal('hide');
    
    // Send to controller
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('CropName', 'myCrop');
    formData.append('CropBase64', base64str);
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/controller/UploadCrop",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: formData,
      success: function (result) {
       // Success
      },
      error: function () {
       // Error
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**c#**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult UploadCrop(string CropName, string CropBase64) { 
    var fullPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), CropName + ".jpg");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, Convert.FromBase64String(CropBase64));
    return Content("uploaded");
}
```